# Scoping in Jest when mocking functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a test where I'm trying to mock a component in two different situations. When I use `jest.fn`. It almost looks like the first test is just taking the value from the second.

```
describe('tests', () => {
  let sampleArray = new Array()
  Array.prototype.test = function() {
    return this.innerArray()
  }
  describe('empty', () => {
    sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => [])
    it('testArray is empty', () => {
      expect(sampleArray.test().length).toEqual(0)
    })
  })

  describe('not empty', () => {
    sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => ['test'])
    it('testArray is not empty', () => {
      console.log(sampleArray.innerArray())
      expect(sampleArray.test().length).toEqual(1)
    })
  })
})
```

When I `console.log` I get the array I expect from innerArray, but it just looks like it doesn't use it.

```
FAIL  test/sample.test.js
  tests
    empty
      ✕ testArray is empty (8ms)
    not empty
      ✓ testArray is not empty (4ms)

  ● tests › empty › testArray is empty

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      0
    Received:
      1
```

edit: If I place it inside the `it` scope, it works. But why can't I do it in the `describe` scope?

```
describe('tests', () => {
  let sampleArray = new Array()
  Array.prototype.test = function() {
    return this.innerArray()
  }
  describe('empty', () => {
    it('testArray is empty', () => {
      sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => [])
      console.log(sampleArray.innerArray())
      expect(sampleArray.test().length).toEqual(0)
    })
  })

  describe('not empty', () => {
    it('testArray is not empty', () => {
      sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => ['test'])
      expect(sampleArray.test().length).toEqual(1)
    })
  })//works
```

Comment: in the first code, first line, do you mean `const sampleArray = new Array()`?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon Adding parenthesis doesn't matter if have you no arguments.

Comment: @Andrew It looks like `it` function is async. Therefore after running `sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => [])`, instead of running corresponding `it` callback, it runs `sampleArray.innerArray = jest.fn(() => ['test'])` which results in test case failing.

Comment: @Prakashsharma Excellent insight. But with that being said, how can I fix it so I don't have to repeat the same 5 lines inside `it` for every single test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically expect the array to be shared among all your tests, you should set it up as follows:

```
Array.prototype.test = function() {
  return this.innerArray()
}

describe('tests', () => {
  let sampleArray

  beforeEach(() =>
    sampleArray = new Array()
  })

  // tests...
});
```

Comment: Works great! Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you can just use `[]` instead of `simpleArray`.

Comment: In this case, that is true. But I wanted to make the closest replication of my actual tests, which are functions.

Comment: Ok, that explains the weird test suite. :)