# How to limit the scope of Jest mocked functions to a single test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I'm writing functional tests using Jest + Testing-Library/React. After days of head scratching, I figured out that when you use `.mockResolvedValue(...)` or `.mockResolvedValueOnce(...)` the scope of the mocking is not limited to that test...

```
import React from "react";
import { render, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import myApi from '../myApi';
jest.mock('../myApi'); // this will load __mocks__/myApi.js (see below)
import { wait } from '@testing-library/dom';
import App from "../components/App";

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});


describe("App", () => {

    test("first test", async () => {

        myApi.get.mockResolvedValueOnce('FOO');

        // App will call myApi.get() once
        const { container, getByText } = render(<App />);

        await waitForElement(
            () => getByText('FOO')
        );

        expect(myApi.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        // This is going to "leak" into the next test
        myApi.get.mockResolvedValueOnce('BAR');

    });

    test("second test", async () => {

        // This is a decoy! The 'BAR' response in the previous test will be returned
        myApi.get.mockResolvedValueOnce('FOO');

        // App will call myApi.get() once (again)
        const { container, getByText } = render(<App />);

        // THIS WILL FAIL!
        await waitForElement(
            () => getByText('FOO')
        );

        expect(myApi.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    });


});
```

Here's what `__mocks__/myApi.js` looks like:

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
};
```

I understand what is happening: `myApi` is imported into the shared scope of both tests. And this is why the `.mockResolvedValue*` applies "across" the tests.

**What is the right way to prevent this?** Tests should be atomic, and not coupled to one another. If I trigger another `get` request in `first test` it should not be able to break `second test`. That's smelly! But what's the correct pattern? I'm thinking about cloning distinct "copies" of `myApi` into the local test scopes... but I worry that will get weird and lead to decreases the confidence of my tests.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855281/scoping-in-jest-when-mocking-functions) which discusses the same topic, but only explains why this happens rather than discussing the right pattern to avoid it.

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  }
```

Comment: Where does `easypuppyApi.get` comes from ? Would you share the `App` component as well?

Comment: @Teneff Sorry that was a copy/paste error. I fixed it so the variable name is now `myApi`.

Comment: I don't think the contents of `<App />` should matter because my question is about Jest. I think it only matters that it calls `myApi.get()` right?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I structure my tests:

- Having a `beforeAll` block in the beginning of the test suit for

  - setting up the mocks
  - clearing the mock functions that are about to be tested
  - rendering the components
  - calling the functions
- Writing separate test cases each described in own `test`**/**`it` block

  - allowing each to have a better,separate description
  - providing better visibility on what has failed in `--verbose` mode

example:

**`App.spec.js`**

```js
describe("App", () => {
  // jest allows nesting of test suits
  // allowing us to have prettier reporting
  // and having scoped variables
  describe("Api.get returning FOO", () => {
    // define variables used in the test suit
    let wrapper;
    // having the setup here
    beforeAll(async () => {
      Api.get.mockClear();
      Api.get.mockResolvedValue("FOO");
      const { container, getByText } = render(<App />);
      // expose the container to the scope
      wrapper = container;

      await waitForElement(() => getByText("FOO"));
    });

    // write the test cases balow
    // each assertion in a separate test block
    test("should call the Api once", () => {
      expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    });

    test("should have been called with data", () => {
      expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ x: "y" });
    });

    test("should match the snapshot", () => {
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });

  describe("Api.get returning BAR", () => {
    // define variables used in the test suit
    let wrapper;

    beforeAll(async () => {
      Api.get.mockClear();
      Api.get.mockResolvedValue("BAR");
      const { container, getByText } = render(<App />);
      // expose the container to the scope
      wrapper = container;

      await waitForElement(() => getByText("FOO"));
    });

    test.todo("describe what is supposed to happen with Api.get");
    test.todo("describe what is supposed to happen container");
  });
});
```

And back to the question - yes, the mock function will be used through the entire test file, but if you have `mockResolvedValueOnce` that has not been consumed (leaked into the next test) either one of the above test cases will fail or you have a poorly written tests.

---

**Edit:**

> As a thought experiment, can you think of a structure that would "solve" that?

To remove return mocked values and implementations after each test you can use

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough example... I like the nested `describe` blocks. You don't see that in most examples but it makes sense. I understand your point about the mocks leaking into the next test causing a failure one way or another. But it still feels problematic for a problem in one test to cause another to fail. Don't we want them to be independent? As a thought experiment, can you think of a structure that would "solve" that?

Comment: @emersonthis if we want them independent we simply write them in separate files