# What is the scope of mocks in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

In summary, I want to know:

1. Are mocks contained to test files or affect multiple files?
2. Is jest scoping the same as JavaScript scoping? A mock in the most inner scope has precedence over outer/global mocks with the same name.
3. A followup question could be: which jest mock methods apply to the units and which apply to local and global scopes?

For example, in the following file system:

```
rootFolder/
  node_modules/
    externalModule/
      - index.js
  __mocks__/
    - externalModule.js
  src/
    - fileA.js
    - fileB.js
    - internalModule.js
    __mocks__/
      internalModule.js
    __tests__/
      - fileA.spec.js
      - fileB.spec.js
```

I have the following questions:

1. Will `jest.mock('../internalModule, () => customImplementation)` in *fileA.spec.js* affect *fileB.spec.js* and vise versa?
2. Similarly, will `jest.mock('externalModule', () => customImplementation)` in *fileA.spec.js* affect *fileB.spec.js* and vise versa?. Doing `jest.mock('Mocking external modules (node_modules)
3. How do global mocks work? Will they be automatically loaded across files or do I have to explicitly do `jest.mock('externalModule')` for it to be initialized
4. Will `jest.mock('externalModule', () => customImplementation)` take takes precedence over global mocks? Will it override the global mock across files?
5. Will `jest.spyOn(internalModule, 'someFunc').mockImplementationOnce(..)` mock the implementation for the life of the unit or only a single call to `someFunc()` would reset the functionality?
6. According to the docs `jest.doMock`, contrary to `jest.mock`, will NOT hoist the mock "up". But, up where? The file? And will it automatically unmock or reset it at the end of the unit? Or will it affect future units as well?
7. Will `jest.unmock('externalModule')` for global mocks, reset it for every file?

I've seen very inconsistent behavior and no documentation explicitly explaining this. Furthermore, I've found documentation to be either all over the place or not concrete enough.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I found other questions with similar titles, such as [How to limit the scope of Jest mocked functions to a single test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893763/how-to-limit-the-scope-of-jest-mocked-functions-to-a-single-test) and [Scoping in Jest when mocking functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855281/scoping-in-jest-when-mocking-functions) but they don't answer my question.

Comment: This is an important question, and there is really no clear answer here. I personally wish to mock something in my jest setup file and have it work for all code run in jest... but it doesn't work, so I'm left tracking down mock scoping problems.

Comment: For the global jest mock you can use jest automock feature - https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#automock-boolean

Answer (score 2):

A spec file runs in isoloation to other specs unless included explicitly by the developer.

The exception here, is, it is possible to set up globals to run.

Treat each test within a spec as it's own application effectively.

They should not interact with each other. But if you import a file, that imports another file (and so on) all those files will be involved in the test and can affect the outcome (depending on what those file do/behave, but thats why we have tests - to find out).

Comment: This is a good answer that should be formatted better to facilitate a quick scan.

Comment: Open to suggestions on formatting, and will edit...?

Answer (score 0):

Some answers:

> 1. Will `jest.mock('../internalModule, () => customImplementation)` in `fileA.spec.js` affect `fileB.spec.js` and vise versa?
> 2. Similarly, will `jest.mock('externalModule', () => customImplementation)` in fileA.spec.js affect fileB.spec.js and vise versa?. Doing `jest.mock('Mocking external modules (node_modules)

> 7. Will `jest.unmock('externalModule')` for global mocks, reset it for every file?

No. As per the docs, if you put that line of code at the top of `fileA.spec.js`, it will only affect the tests contained within that file and not affect `fileB.spec.js`. It should be "unmocked" at the teardown of the `describe` blocks in your file.

> 4. Will `jest.mock('externalModule', () => customImplementation)` take takes precedence over global mocks? Will it override the global mock across files?

Yes, putting this in your local file will override the global mock.

> 5. Will `jest.spyOn(internalModule, 'someFunc').mockImplementationOnce(..)` mock the implementation for the life of the unit or only a single call to someFunc() would reset the functionality?

This depends on how the original is mocked. My guess here is that the second call would be `undefined` and not call the underlying implementation. Doing anything else would lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Could you please provide the official documentation link to this "as per the docs"?